# Virtualbox Mac OSX 10.11 Guest OS Corrupted Hard Drive ; "Incorrect number of thread records"

Tags: xcode, macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox, osx-elcapitan

I have successfully installed and run the OSX 10.11 on virtualbox a few while ago and I was able to successfully work with it and install xcode 7 on it and work with it without problems.

Now after a few days I have come to it and I have run the virtual machine and got the following error!!

[image: Mac OSX boot screen]

It says: "Checking catalog file, incorrect number of thread records". It keeps working a while and finishes with closing the VM.

I didn't make any changes to it. I even created a new machine again using the existing ".VMDK" file and still no change.

I really need the data on it. Can you please help me with fixing the virtual machine? I have a .VMDK file with the size of 43 GB.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks GOD, I could finally find a solution for this problem. I launched another Mac virtual machine and followed [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkTDNwHTW8w) on Youtube and installed Diskwarrior on the vm and from this vm, I could repair the other .VMDK file using Diskwarrior. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, found a simplier solution. I booted the virtual machine with Ubuntu live cd.

In terminal:

```
sudo apt install hfsprogs
# HFS file system consistency check, use fdisk -l to find your disk indetifier
sudo fsck.hfsplus /dev/sda2
```